# Joining two tables within Laravel Controller

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have two tables that I am joining within my controller - `thought_journal_entries` and `emotions`. They have a many-to-many relationship which has been added to the models.

I believe my code will work but I am getting the error:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.

I think my code is almost there I'm just not sure if I'm looping correctly to get the `emotion->image` field

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$thought_journal_entries = ThoughtJournalEntry::with('emotions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

foreach($thought_journal_entries as $thought_journal_entry) {
    foreach($thought_journal_entry->$emotions as $emotion) {
        $emotion->image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $emotion->image);
    }
}
return $thought_journal_entries;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Config you database file to `utf8_unicode_ci`. Check the file config/database.php :

   ```
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   ```
2. Make sure your Mysql databases is set to `utf8` and MySQL’s `utf8mb4` is better
3. Make sure your file character set to UTF-8 without BOM (Byte order mark)